# Pass \n and other raw characters into html input field

Tags: python, flask, escaping

I'm writing a flask application that allows users to specify parameters for batch jobs - one of the parameters I want the user to provide is a delimiter - either for csv files, or as an end-of-line terminator for text files.

I have a json document that contains the default values for a given job, and I use these to pre-populate a series of form input elements that the user has the option to edit.

The problem I have is when a default parameter is tab, or newline, these are represented in my json as `\t` or `\n` respectively - but when injecting these values into my html page building code, they're interpreted as an actual tab, or newline respectively.

```
data_content_template = """<label for="{pipe}_{e}_{dsk}">{dsk}:</label><br>
           <input type="text" id="{pipe}_{e}_{dsk}" name="{pipe}_{e}_{dsk}" value="{dse}"><br>"""

form_contents=[]
for e,dsi in enumerate(content.get("data_source",[])):
    for dk,de in dsi.items():
        form_contents.append(data_content_template.format(pipe=escape(content.get("pipe")),
                                                          e=e,
                                                          dsk=escape(dk),
                                                          dse=escape(de)))
```

Here, I'm using flask.escape to try and force these values into their text boxes without converting them into white-space. But when I look at the html source, it comes out like this:

```
<input type="text" id="ref_data_0_newline" name="ref_data_0_newline" value="
"><br>
```

How do I pass through `\n` in its raw, unaltered form so that it displays a backslash followed by an n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want flask `safe` filter ... `escape` is the opposite of what you need

```
{{ form_content | safe }}
```

it should then render the html

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to do a string replace for '\n' to '\\n' with double-backslash?  If that doesn't work, you could try encoding '\n' to '&#92;n'.

You could also try encoding the newline directly to '&#10;'.

You can rewrite something like this JS example below into python to convert any special characters that aren't in a whitelist into their entity codes.  My example below converts &#10; into 
 but you can delete or comment out that line depending on whether you want the newlines to show as linebreaks in your html.

```
/**
 * Turn all chars not in w (whitelist) into their html-friendly character codes. Converts line-breaks to br.
 *
 * @param {string} text The text to escape.
 * @return The escaped text.
 * @customfunction
 */
function escapeText_html (text){
  var s ="", w="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890,.!?;-$%# ";
  for(i=0; i<text.length; i++){
    c = text.substring(i, i+1);
    if(w.indexOf(c) != -1 ){
      s += c;
    }else{
      s += "&#" + c.charCodeAt(0) + ";";
    }
  }
  s=replaceAll(s, "&#10;", "<br />");
  return s;  
}
```